# SwiftUI - Memory Management

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, swiftui

OK, so I'm looking to improve memory within my app.

I have enabled `Live Memory Allocation` for my project and I'm using the `Debug Graph Tool`. I'm looking at the backtraces, and coming across issues, which in total honesty, does not make sense to me. I've, to the best of my knowledge, removed strong references, but I am getting issues with parts of my code where I just don't understand/see the issue. And example of this is:

```
struct ProductScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let view = UIScrollView()
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return ProductScrollView.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    @State var currentPage: Int
    @Binding var products: [ProductModel]
    func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UIScrollView {

        if view.superview == .none {
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: ProductCell(products: $products, currentPage: currentPage, pageCount: products.count)
        ) <---- Debugger seems to indicate this with the message "Thread 1"



        childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((products.count)))
        view.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((products.count)))
        
        view.addSubview(childView.view)
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.isPagingEnabled = true
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        }
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        uiView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((products.count)))
        for i in 0..<uiView.subviews.count {
            uiView.subviews[i].frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * CGFloat((products.count)))
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var parent: ProductScrollView

        init(parent1: ProductScrollView){
            parent = parent1
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let index = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.y / UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            parent.currentPage = index
      
        }

        deinit {
            print("Coordiante scroll view desroted")
        }
    }
}
```

Which doesn't make complete sense to me, however, I believe the line:

```
 return ProductScrollView.Coordinator(parent1: self)
```

May be the issue?

I'll even have the debugger point to functions that are performed on my `onAppear` method.

Could someone please help as to what I can do to better understand these issues and eliminate them?

Edit -

To delve even further, this line appears in my backtrace:

```
static var FEEDBACK = FeedbackAPI()
```

Is it due to creating a new instance everytime?

Comment: Memory leak issue is sometimes more complicated and ambiguous than we think. Your code doesn't seem wrong. I guess any other parts is likely to cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By design we need to instantiate view inside `makeView`, so SwiftUI manages UIView lift-cycle to be the same as representable view, like

```
struct ProductScrollView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return ProductScrollView.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }

    @State var currentPage: Int
    @Binding var products: [ProductModel]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) ->  UIScrollView {
        let view = UIScrollView()   // << here !!

// ... other code
}
```